# Unable to launch AVD in emulator from Android Studio in Ubuntu 32 bit

Tags: android, ubuntu-15.04

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

> Output: emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable. CPU
>   acceleration status: KVM is not installed on this machine (/dev/kvm is
>   missing).

I tried several steps mentioned in related posts but nothing worked fine. That's why posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try to use [`Genymotion`](http://www.genymotion.com/) as your emulator? It is a fast emulator.

Comment: Yes, I am checking this option now.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message mentions you should set up `kvm` at first.

Set up `kvm` on your Ubuntu machine as refering [the official Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation).

Comment: I tried all these steps already and finally it shown your CPU doesn't support. I checked BIOS setting and didn't fine any VT enable settings. There was some accelerometer settings disabled, I enabled it and checked but the result is same.

Comment: @Viswanathan `kvm` requires a certain CPU which supports Intel-VT or AMD-V. Does your CPU support one of them?

Comment: Thanks for the info, @hata. I have no idea about how to check this. But I know it will work on this CPU because I am able to run AVD in Windows 7 running on the same machine. It seems like some limitation with Ubuntu 32-bit. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have checked with kvm-ok and it shows that processor does not support virtualization.